# After http -> https nginx does not find static content

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, http-status-code-404

I had a working setup for static file serving with nginx, using http.

Later, when I switched to https, changing the port from 80 to 443 as well as adding ssl certificate and key, the web server cannot find the static files any more. I get 404 responses for all static files. This is my nginx configuration file:

```
http {

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;


    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; 
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    upstream http_backend {
            server 127.0.0.1:3001;
            keepalive 32;
    }

    server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  test.com;

            # Redirect to https
            location / {
                    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
            }
    }

    server {
            listen 443 default_server ssl;
            server_name localhost;
            root /var/www/myblog/app/resources/public;

            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/key.pem;

            location / {
                    proxy_redirect off;

                    proxy_pass              http://http_backend;
                    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto https;

                    access_log /var/www/logs/myblog.access.log;
                    error_log /var/www/logs/myblog.error.log;
            }

            location ^~ /(css|js) {
                    root /var/www/myblog/app/resources/public;
            }
    }
}
```

My access log:

```
37.201.226.254 - - [26/Aug/2018:06:41:25 +0000] "GET /js/compiled/foo.js HTTP/1.1" 404 38 "https://www.test.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"    
37.201.226.254 - - [26/Aug/2018:06:41:25 +0000] "GET /css/mui.css HTTP/1.1" 404 38 "https://www.test.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"           
37.201.226.254 - - [26/Aug/2018:06:41:25 +0000] "GET /css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://www.test.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0"
```

The files are in `/var/www/myblog/app/resources/public`: this is configured as root. I run the web server from `/var/www/myblog/app`.

Bear in mind this is my first deployment with NGINX. Does anyone have an idea what I forgot to configure to serve static files with https? My OS is linux.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem through random trial and error. For some reason, changing

```
        location ^~ /(css|js) {
                root /var/www/myblog/app/resources/public;
        }
```

to

```
        location ~ ^/(css/|js/) {
                root /var/www/myblog/app/resources/public/;
        }
```

seems to work.

Comment: For anyone wondering what _some_ reason might be, it's because the `^~` modifier is a prefix modifier, not a regex one. Nginx has 2 regex modifiers, `~` for case sensitive matching and `~*` for case insensitive matching. These three all contain a tilde `~`, but the similarity ends there. `^~` tells Nginx that if this location block is the longest matching prefix location for the current request then select this block to process the request, without evaluating any of the regex location blocks.

Comment: Thank you very much for showing the solution. I literally lost 4 days with this issue.